# how to delete all files with a specific extension in google drive

Tags: python, google-drive-api

I have about 200k files with .tif extension in my root folder of google drive that i need to delete.

The python code i wrote only transfers / deletes the few files that we can see at an instance (we need to scroll down in the drive and let them 'load' to see more of them)

I am willing to delete all other files as well if there is a shortcut to do so.

Cntl + A does not work either, it just selects a same few files that we can see in an instance.

```
import shutil
import os

source = '/content/gdrive/My Drive'
dest1 = '/content/gdrive/My Drive/toDelete'


files = os.listdir(source)

for f in files:
    if (f.endswith(".tif")):
        shutil.move(f, dest1)
```

---

```
dir_name = "/content/gdrive/My Drive"
test = os.listdir(dir_name)

for item in test:
    if item.endswith(".tif"):
        os.remove(os.path.join(dir_name, item))
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to delete multiple files at once using Google Drive API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33692184/how-to-delete-multiple-files-at-once-using-google-drive-api) - that uses the v2 API, though, but v3 should be about the same?

Comment: @JeppeSpanggaard he said Google drive. Not his hard drive.

Comment: To build onto @DaImTo 's answer below, you can find the documentation for the [delete method](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/delete) and the [list method](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/list) to be of assistance. You should also take a look into the [Python Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/quickstart/python) which will help you get everything set up to work with the API

Answer (score 2):

First you need to search for all the files that contain in the name and are in your root directory once you have those you can start deleting them.

I recommend you test this without the delete first to make sure its listing the files your after I am not responsible for this deleting stuff :)

page_token = None

```
while True:
    response = drive_service.files().list(q="name contains '.tif' and 'root' in parents",
                                          spaces='drive',
                                          fields='nextPageToken, files(id, name)',
                                          pageToken=page_token).execute()
    for file in response.get('files', []):
        # Process change
        print 'Found file: %s (%s)' % (file.get('name'), file.get('id'))
        #drive_service.files().delete(fileId=file.get('id')).execute()
    page_token = response.get('nextPageToken', None)
    if page_token is None:
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Use `glob`.
2. Use `pathlib` for path manipulation.

```py
import pathlib
import shutil

source = pathlib.Path('/content/gdrive/My Drive')
dest1 = pathlib.Path('/content/gdrive/My Drive/toDelete')
dest1.mkdir(exist_ok=True)

for f in source.glob("*.tif"):
    shutil.move(f, dest1.joinpath(f.name))
```

Comment: this does not works, it only deletes the few top files