# Google Drive Api PHP Delete Multiple Files

Tags: php, file, google-drive-api, delete-file

Help...

Got a problem deleting multiple files in google drive api using php.

i have found a link for batch delete but it use python.
im trying to recreate it using php but it does not work.
anyone help me with what im trying to achive..

[The Python Version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33692184/how-to-delete-multiple-files-at-once-using-google-drive-api)

Method 1:

```
<?php
    include_once('variables.php');
    $service = connectGoogleDrive();

    $optParams = array(
        'pageSize' => 1000,
        'fields' => 'nextPageToken, files(id, name, webViewLink)'
    );
    $results = $service->files->listFiles($optParams);

    $service->getClient()->setUseBatch(true);
    $batch = $service->createBatch();
    foreach ($results->getFiles() as $file) {
        $request = $service->files->delete($file->getId());
        $batch->add($request);
    }
    $results = $batch->execute();
    foreach ($results as $result) {
        if ($result instanceof Google_Service_Exception) {
            // Handle error
            printf($result);
        }
    }
    $service->getClient()->setUseBatch(false);

?>
```

Thanks in advance. There's no error appearing

**EDIT 1**
As per Aaron Jonk's link; I found the batch example...
Mine doesn't differ much. It has a optParam mine doesnt.
**$request = $service->files->delete($file->getId());** <- Differ

```
$client->setUseBatch(true);
/************************************************
 We then create a batch, and add each query we
 want to execute with keys of our choice - these
 keys will be reflected in the returned array.
************************************************/
$batch = $service->createBatch();
$optParams = array('filter' => 'free-ebooks');
$req1 = $service->volumes->listVolumes('Henry David Thoreau', $optParams);
$batch->add($req1, "thoreau");
$req2 = $service->volumes->listVolumes('George Bernard Shaw', $optParams);
$batch->add($req2, "shaw");
/************************************************
  Executing the batch will send all requests off
  at once.
 ************************************************/
$results = $batch->execute();
```

**EDIT 2**
There is no problem to begin with. sadly i forgot that maximum of 1000 files thats why i think there was an error. im expecting an instant delete files.

Comment: https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-php-client https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/quickstart/php <-- Maybe take a look at these?

Comment: There was no error my code works HAHAHAH